# How can I find out all the stores in a particular street before going there?

Tags: online-resources, planning, shopping

If I am going to shopping destination, I would love to be able to browse through all the stores on the street before going there so I know what my options are. I am most interested in the fashionable streets of cities, like Rodeo Drive in LA, Newbury Street in Boston, the Brera in Milan, Queen Street in New Zealand, etc.

How can I find out all the stores in such areas before I go?

Comment: Google street view

Comment: As a Kiwi, the thought of Queen St being fashionable made me laugh, but in some ways you're probably correct.  I'd also vouch for Google Street view, or frankly Google Maps as you can often look at levels in a building

Comment: I tried to use street view and I find it way too slow and cumbersome. It might work for someone who wanted to look at just one place, but it is not practical as a touring mechanism. The image reload just takes too long.

Answer (score 5):

I like the places you have mentioned.  The comments indicate that the first steps are to use the Street View facility at Google Maps. This answer accepts that as a given and focuses on interesting alternatives involving local trade associations and civic entities...

### Rodeo Drive

There is a Twitter feed [@RodeoDrive](https://twitter.com/rodeodrivebh?lang=en) whose banner note reads...

> The Official Twitter of Rodeo Drive in Beverly Hills✨ Representing the
> retailers, hotels & landowners on the world-renowned boulevard!

The feed includes lots of photos and videos of the retailers and shop fronts. There is also a dedicated site for [Rodeo Drive](http://rodeodrive-bh.com/) listing the retailers, but the Twitter feed appears to be more vibrant and dynamic.

And finally, the city of Beverly Hills has a hash tag [#BHOpenLate](https://twitter.com/hashtag/BHOpenLate?src=hash) which is dedicated to all the shops that are, well... open late.

### Newbury Street

Unsurprisingly, given the civic presence of Rodeo Drive on Twitter, there's a Twitter feed [@NewburyStreet1](https://twitter.com/newburystreet1?lang=en). Their banner note reads...

> Official Page of Newbury Street League Representing Boston's most
> fashionable street Check in for updates on all of the latest that
> Newbury Street has to offer

Their static site is at [Newbury Street League](http://www.newburystreetleague.org/) and that's where you would see the population of shops (actually members of their league). But again, the Twitter feed shows which retailers are having a sale.

### the Brera in Milan

This is supported by the City of Milan's feed ([@ComuneMI](https://twitter.com/comunemi?lang=en)), their banner note reads...

> Informazioni, notizie e servizi da Palazzo Marino. Linea diretta nei
> giorni feriali, 9.30-18.30 | The City of Milan. Monitored
> 9.30am-6.30pm Monday to Friday

It covers a much broader area than shopping, but they provide a phone number and appear to engage the public via Twitter DM's.

There is also a static site '[Walks of Italy](https://www.walksofitaly.com/blog/milan/shopping-in-milan)' which gives a walk-through of the Brera zone.

### Queen Street

To learn the shops on this street you would use Street View.

### Gum

Gum is arguably the most elegant shopping experience on the planet so I'll add it.  There appears to be no dedicated Twitter feed offered by a civic or trade association, but the query at [Red Square Shopping](https://twitter.com/search?q=red%20square%20shopping&src=typd) provides photos and video walk-through's made by random tweets.  There are about 100 shops in total.

There is a static site at [Gum Red Square](https://gumrussia.com/shops/) that lists all the stores by category.  For Vosstaniya Square, there's a hash tag [#vistaniya](https://twitter.com/hashtag/vosstaniya) but obtaining a full list of merchants to be out-of-reach.

### Bond Street

Finally, there is a dedicated Twitter feed at [@bondstreetshops](https://twitter.com/bondstreetshops?lang=en) and their banner note reads...

> Bond Street Shops, London, Jewellery, Watches, jewellers, Bond Street,
> Shopping in London, London Shops.

They have a static site at [Bondstreet Shops](http://www.bondstreetshops.co.uk/) where you can get a list of their featured shops.

---

Of course Google Maps can be used in shopping venues almost everywhere, Canal Street, Nevsky Prospect, Regent Street, and others.